# Where did podman put my container?

Tags: rhel, container, podman, alma-linux

I just installed AlmaLinux 9 (a Red Hat 9 clone), and setup containers with podman which is the new standard for RH9.  Following some instructions online, I succesfully downloaded and ran a container as follows:

```
docker run -d \
  --name homeassistant \
  --privileged \
  --restart=unless-stopped \
  -e TZ=MY_TIME_ZONE \
  -v /PATH_TO_YOUR_CONFIG:/config \
  --network=host \
  ghcr.io/home-assistant/home-assistant:stable
```

I can confirm it's running, so now I want to setup a systemd service file to start the 'homeassistant' container on bootup.  I tried to locate the container image file but I can't!  I checked the locations listed in /etc/containers/storage.conf and it lists

```
runroot = "/run/containers/storage"
graphroot = "/var/lib/containers/storage"
```

But neither of these hold the container I'm running (in fact /var/lib/containers doesn't even contain a storage subdirectory).  So where is the container that my docker command downloaded?

---

Update:
I issued the command above as a temporary user, and would like to move the container from the temporary user (hass) to root user.  I thought I would move the file.  (But I'm happy to delete and redownload too.)  As a newbie I would like to know where this container file/image/dir is located.

My goal is to create a systemd file as shown [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/managing_containers/running_containers_as_systemd_services_with_podman) and I think running it as root will make life easier (at least while I learn).  So I need to move the container image to a different user.

I can't figure out how to list installed containers, move them (to new user), delete them, etc.  The 'podmas ps -a' lists the one running container, but only high level info.

Answer (score 2):

Podman stores container-related files under `~/.local/share/containers/` (`~` being the home directory of whichever user ran the container).

In your scenario, you can save some download time by copying that directory to root’s home directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /root/.local/share
sudo cp -a ~/.local/share/containers /root/.local/share
```

But you’ll still need to run `podman pull` to make sure everything’s set up correctly.

Comment: I checked in ~/.local/share/containers and there are only 2 subdirs, and neither matches homeassistant.  Subdirs are 'cache' and 'storage', and within 'storage' looks like default folder structure only

Comment: You won’t find anything named `home-assistant`, the directories under `…/containers` use hashes as names. It’s not clear to me why you want to find the files however — you don’t need to know where things live to start your container at boot, just run your `docker run` command.

Comment: I added more explanation to the question

Comment: @StephenKitt *It’s not clear to me why you want to find the files however* I need to know where are the container's config files

Comment: @StephenKitt There is no `.local` directory in root's home who runs the container

Comment: @Clodoaldo please [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), I suspect your use case is not the same as TSG’s.